# Trying to edit the single page from a Custom Post

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, pages, templates

I have a custom post type where I can create pages in.("article.php")
It automatically uses the template "single.php" when I create a page, although I want to change some things in it without effecting some other pages on the website.
I tried making a single-article.php file, but it is still using the single.php template page. Based on the documentation it should work. What could I've done wrong?

Comment: Do you mean custom post type?

Comment: Is `article.php` a page template ?

Comment: Aparently both @bravokeyl and I are confused about what you mean. Perhaps you should refrase your question to explain your problem more clearly.

Comment: I tried describing it as clear as possible.

Comment: Could you post the code of article.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you want to change the single page**

`page-{page-slug}` is a good choice if you want the page template for specific page only and not multiple pages.

Check out his [custom page template for specific page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#creating-a-custom-page-template-for-one-specific-page)

**If you are talking about custom post type**

We can use `single-$posttype.php` , here `$posttype` is your custom post type slug.

WordPress template Hierarchy for single post page's custom post is in the order of :

```
single-$posttype.php ==> single.php ==> singular.php(WP 4.3+)
```

So if a custom post single page is requested, WP first looks for `single-$posttype` file if it's available it uses that file else it goes to `single.php` and so on as the above order.

Refer to [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) for more details.

Comment: the custom page is named article.php ,and i tried single-article.php with no succes. The pages are already created though and they dont change even though the single-article.php is totally different then single.php

Comment: It's more than 1 page, i need to change the template of all the custom post pages.

Comment: @cynen , when you say *custom post pages* ,what exactly do you mean?

Comment: In the wordpress backoffice , i have a tab (i think thats called a custom post) where i can create pages . I also have a webpage on the website which loops through these custom post pages. And if you click on one of the pages , the "single.php" page is showed. Instead of the "single.php" i want the "single-article.php" page to be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are talking about a custom post type the answer is [right in the codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post). Generate a template called `single-{post-type}.php` and WP takes care of the rest.

Comment: he custom page is named article.php ,and i tried single-article.php with no succes. The pages are already created though and they dont change even though the single-article.php is totally different then single.php